# Shared Preference Force close

Tags: android

My Program gets Force closed when i execute this code.. can anyone tell me..whats the solution..
package com.test.sharedPreferences;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sharedpreference extends Activity {
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Preference",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("keyBoolean", true);
      editor.putFloat("keyFloat", 1.0f);
      editor.putInt("keyInt", 1);
      editor.putLong("keyLong", 1000000L);
      editor.putString("keyString", "Hello Android");
      editor.commit();

//    boolean dataFromPrefBool = pref.getBoolean("keyBoolean", false);
//    float dataFromPrefflaot = pref.getFloat("keyFloat", 0.0f);
      int dataFromPrefInt = pref.getInt("keyInt", 0);
//    long dataFromPrefLong = pref.getLong("keyLong", 0);
//    String dataFromPrefString = pref.getString("keyString", null);

      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setText(dataFromPrefInt);
      setContentView(tv);

     }
    }
```

Comment: what is the exception exactly? logcat output pls

Comment: where is your preference name and static string value's on declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: There was no error in code..i simply pasted that code in another project.and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you write getInt....that means you are opening the editor.

So first open the editor and den write the getInt code.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Preference",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
int dataFromPrefInt = pref.getInt("keyInt", 0);
```

Comment: M sorry for the statement i have written about the editor. But the code I have pasted is working fine. So please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem.  You're opening up the shared preferences using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` (ie, read-only mode) here:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Preference",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

and then following that up by trying to EDIT the shared preferences here:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("keyBoolean", true);
...
editor.commit();
```

Doesn't something about that seem incorrect to you?  If not, [here's the documentation to clarify things.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)